# Attribute for html tag

Tags: html, lang

I explored some source codes from some websites and I found this attribute in html tag: "data-scribe-reduced-action-queue". But I'm not found some document for describe it. Do you have references for me? Thanks.
This is a example from Twitter:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="lt-ie10 ie8" lang="pt data-scribe-reduced-action-queue="true""><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="lt-ie10 ie9" lang="pt data-scribe-reduced-action-queue="true""><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html lang="pt" data-scribe-reduced-action-queue="true"><!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used to store custom data private to the page or application

Check this:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp